# Swift: Audio start and stop in .1 second

Tags: swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I've followed every post on Net but none solved this issue.
The sound start and stop right immediately like after 0.1 second. I can hear a sound very quickly.

here is my code from where it matters:
...

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("bgMusic", ofType: "mp3")
    let bgMusicURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(path!)

    var backgroundMusicPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!

    do{
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
        try backgroundMusicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: bgMusicURL)
        backgroundMusicPlayer!.prepareToPlay()
        backgroundMusicPlayer!.play()

    }catch {
        print ("ERROR")
    }
```

...

Comment: do you have anything else running on the threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the function that contains your code snippet ends, the garbage collector will come to deallocate your `backgroundMusicPlayer`. Try either making `backgroundMusicPlayer` a global variable, or having some kind of static variable that holds it.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Can you please mark the answer as correct?